# Clojure sort map object key

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

I have a flowers object;

Like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okFes.png)

```
   :flowers
           {:flower_1  "orchid"
            :flower_2  "Gazania"
            :flower_3  "Cockscomb"
            :flower_4  "Yarrow"  
            :flower_5  "Trollius" 
            :flower_6  "Soapwort" 
            :flower_7  "Gardenia"
            :flower_8  "Antirrhinum" 
            :flower_9  "Ginger" 
            :flower_10 "Trollius"
            :flower_11 "Gazania"
            :flower_12 "Knapweed"
             }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei3uY.png)

When ı upload object to state.  Mixed sort,
Like this.

So ı decide sort flowers by key when get flowers from state.

Why ı need, ı sort flowers keys,
Because get glowers after listed in views.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv0j3.png)

I need sort

```
[:div 
  [:h1 "Set Flowers"]
        (for [[key value] @flowers]
            (edit-flower-input key value))]
```

```
(defn edit-flower-input [id label]
  (let [value (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/get-flower id])]
  [:div {:key id :class "row"}
  [:label id ]
    [:input.input {:value @value
                    :class "form-control"
                    :on-change #(re-frame/dispatch [::events/update-flower id (-> % .-target .-value)])
                    :type "text"
                    :placeholder label}]
    ] ))
```

Comment: Why do you need those unwieldy keys? Why not keep the order in a field
or just use a vector for the order?

Comment: @cfrick  because this is how an object is returned to me from the api. The incoming object is kept directly in the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```clj
[:div 
  [:h1 "Set Flowers"]
        (for [[key value] (sort-by key @flowers)]
            (edit-flower-input key value))]
```

Comment: nice but look like   flower_1  flower_10 flower_11 flower_2.   ı guess ı use split key.